# Vaadin SessionDestroyListener session access

Tags: session, vaadin

Is it possible to access session attributes inside the  Vaadin SessionDestroyListener ? Or is it called after session getting destroyed ? 
How the call back order regarding to HttpSessionListener, before or after ?

Comment: Unless something changed from Vaadin 7.4.3 the attributes should still be available when the `SessionDestroyListener` is called. I've used it successfully in a project by [registering](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.session) such a listener with my custom `SpringVaadinServlet`, and I was able to do some cleanup based on attributes saved in the vaadin session. What's your problem?

Comment: @Morfic, I'm accessing user details in the session and login out user from an authentication server. For that functionality it is required to get user details from the session that's being destroyed. I noticed if I get session details after some other tasks in the listener i'm not getting user details form the session. Then moved the code as first thing in the listener and now it's working as expected. Needed to clarify the behavior.

Comment: If you're spawning some threads then yes, it's possible that its state changes meanwhile, so if you get your required info from the start you should be fine. Otherwise, I don't see how this could happen so you'll need to provide some more info on your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

While the session object is available by calling `sessionDestroyEvent.getSession()`, its state is `CLOSING` <del>and all attributes have already been removed from it</del> (rather simple to test this...).

**EDIT**

**@Morfic** is completely right, so he gets the credit: when in a `SessionDestroyListener`'s `sessionDestroy()` method, the session's attributes are, indeed, ***still available*** (I was not careful in my tests; re-did them, using the latest Vaadin release, 8.0.4).